# Can't find NAV 2013 R2 tables in the SQL database

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-nav, navision

I'm currently migrating our NAV 2009 tables to our new NAV 2013 R2 database.
I was able to upgrade, import and compile the tables as .fob objects in the new database's object designer, but it seems like they are not really inside the database.

Executing this

```
use oldDB;
select name from sys.tables;
```

yields the system table names along with all other tables in the style of `company$table`. However if I run this

```
use newDB;
select name from sys.tables;
```

shows only the system tables.

How is this possible? Are tables saved somewhere else than inside of the database?
Since I only imported the tables into the NAV 2013 R2 database there is no company in this db. Could this cause problems?

**EDIT**: Security rights shouldn't be the issue, since I'm logged in as SA.

**EDIT 2**: Added pictures of new and old database tables.

[image: Tables of the old database]
[image: Tables of the new database]

Comment: What does SQL Server Management Studio show if you expand the Tables folder under the newDB? The style Company$Table has not changed in NAV 2013, R2 or NAV 2015.

Comment: @ShadowXVII Same information as the sql query provided.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it.

It seems like SQL Server cannot show NAV tables as long as there is no company. Since the database was a blank database with just the tables imported, there also was no company.

I was able to create one through the Dynamics Administration Shell:

```
PS C:\> New-NAVCompany

CompanyName: My Company
ServerInstance: DynamicsNAV71
```

Comment: In SQL a table is created for each separate company. So if you create a second company in NAV, your will see a second table with dbo.companyname$"table name".

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the "no company in this db" in your OP. 
Yes of course the tables won't exist until the company is created. You can use the classic environment also with File > Database > New.